# A question with two parts

Tags: discussion

I'm writing a question which has two parts. The 1st part can be answered independently from the 2nd, and it is easier to formulate the 2nd one once the 1st part is answered. However, both parts together give a better context for the question and may invite unanticipated answers that do not split the problem into part 1, part 2 the way I see it. Should I post a single question or two questions (for each part)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does the second question depend on the answer to the first?** If so, I think you really have to wait until you have an answer to the first.

Which leads me to wonder: **do you *know* the answer to the first question**; do you *think* you know it and simple want a reliable source?

Comment: I don't have a clear answer to any of the two, so it seems I better go setp-by-step. Thanks.